# Android API 25: Permission error while saving to PRIVATE storage

Tags: android, io, file-storage, android-7.1-nougat

Prior to API 25, it was no problem saving a file to the private app storage. However, with compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion set to 25, this is not possible - whenever I am trying to read/write a file (which is in the app-private storage), I get PERMISSION_DENIED and my app crashes.

Example 1: This is the exception Realm throws upon calling Realm.getDefaultInstance():

> io.realm.exceptions.RealmFileException: Unable to open a realm at path
>   '/data/data/[PACKAGE_NAME]/files/default.realm.management'.
>   Please use a path where your app has read-write permissions. in
>   /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp
>   line 81 Kind: PERMISSION_DENIED.

Example 2: This is the exception the app throws upon trying to persist a file (while opening FileOutputStream):

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/[PACKAGE_NAME]/files/[FILE_NAME] (Permission denied)

As already said, I have none of these issues on API 24. Does somebody have an idea what the possible cause of this problem is?

Comment: That's not a problem in general. Try fully uninstalling the app (i.e., from Settings) and reinstalling.

Comment: well dangit, that really helped...... so why did it happen anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app lost its ability to work with its own files. Possible reasons include:

- Because you changed the `android:sharedUserId` value for your app — if you ever add/change/remove this attribute in the manifest, you have to fully uninstall and reinstall the app
- Something to do with multiple user accounts on the device on which you are testing, perhaps tied into...
- ...Some bug in Android that you accidentally tripped over

Comment: Not sure which one it was, but reinstalling definitely helped, thanks again!